# The function returns false when only last variable is answered

Tags: python

```
if select == (board[0] and board[1] and board[2]):
        print ("game ended - you win!")
        game = False
```

please see code above, when board 0 and 1 is entered by itself. It is fine. However if two is entered by itself without any other key it triggers the code below. I want the function, once all paramaters are the same then it will print the below. If you could help I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Something like `all(i == select for i in board)`

Comment: Ooh I like that one @S3DEV

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```py
if select == board[0] == board[1] == board[2]:
    print("game ended - you win!")
    game = False
```

Comment: What if board has four elements?  Five elements? Six elements?  (See where I’m going with this ... ?)